# Calling back to a main file from a dofile in lua

Tags: lua

Say i have two files:

One is called mainFile.lua:

```
function altDoFile(name)
    dofile(debug.getinfo(1).source:sub(debug.getinfo(1).source:find(".*\\")):sub(2)..name)
end

altDoFile("libs/caller.lua")

function callBack()
    print "called back"
end

doCallback()
```

The other called caller.lua, located in a libs folder:

```
function doCallback()
    print "performing call back"
    _G["callBack"]()
end
```

The output of running the first file is then:

```
"performing call back"
```

Then nothing more, i'm missing a line!

Why is callBack never getting executed? is this intended behavior, and how do i get around it?

The fact that the function is getting called from string is important, so that can't be changed.

UPDATE:
I have tested it further, and the _G["callBack"] does resolve to a  function (type()) but it still does not get called

Comment: Are you sure the path separator is \ instead of `/` ?

Comment: well, no, the altDoFile function is something i got from someone else. but the file does load, so that is not the problem.

Comment: @Delusional Logic: "the file does load, so that is not the problem"   Then you should remove it and repost. If it turns out it *is* the problem, you've found a valuable clue. If it's *not* the problem, you've removed a major complicating distraction from your post. Either way, reducing your code to the smallest thing that reproduces the problem is win/win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use [dofile](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-dofile)?

It seems that the purpose of `altDoFile` is to replace the running script's filename with the script you want to call thereby creating an absolute path. In this case the path for `caller.lua` is a relative path so you shouldn't need to change anything for Lua to load the file.

Refactoring your code to this:

```
dofile("libs/caller.lua")

function callBack()
    print "called back"
end

doCallback()
```

Seems to give the result you are looking for:

```
$ lua mainFile.lua 
performing call back
called back
```

Just as a side note, `altDoFile` throws an error if the path does not contain a `\` character. Windows uses the backslash for path names, but other operating systems like Linux and MacOS do not.

In my case running your script on Linux throws an error because `string.find` returns nill instead of an index.

```
lua: mainFile.lua:2: bad argument #1 to 'sub' (number expected, got nil)
```

If you need to know the working path of the main script, why not pass it as a command line argument:

```
C:\LuaFiles> lua mainFile.lua C:/LuaFiles
```

Then in Lua:

```
local working_path = arg[1] or '.'
dofile(working_path..'/libs/caller.lua')
```

Comment: I kept it in there because i needed it in my original script. i have since reworked it, and it now works. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to be able to walk back up one directory, you can also modify the loader

```
 package.path = ";../?.lua" .. package.path;
```

So then you could run your file by doing:

```
require("caller")
```

Answer (score -1):

dofile "../Untitled/SensorLib.lua" --use backpath librarys

Best Regards
   K.

Comment: This is a very late answer to something that already has an answer and doesn't seem to add anything to the original answer. Is this an alternate answer? If so, please add some context to clarify since this is a pretty terse response.